# How to Use Aura Attribute Length Value in Lighting Accordian Section Label

Tags: lightning-aura-components, label, accordion

Looking to use an Aura Attribute length value for a Lightning Accordion Section. Pretty basic but i can not figure out how to do the length value minus 2 within the label. I'd like to keep it as simple as possible but could certainly use the controller and an additional attribute but was wondering if there is anyway to do simple math in a dynamic label

```
label="{! con.policyOwner + ' (' + con.data.length + ')'}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's at least two ways you can do this:

```
label="{! con.policyOwner + ' (' + sub(con.data.length, 2) + ')'}">
```

`sub(x, y)` subtracts `y` from `x` and returns the result.

```
label="{! con.policyOwner + ' (' + (con.data.length - 2) + ')'}">
```

To avoid confusion in the parser, use parentheses to group the math operation.

You can see other [functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm) and [operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_operators.htm) that you can use in expressions in the documentation.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I had tried to use the -2 but did not use the parentheses correclty. Great stuff